# How to get the text from textarea in php?

Tags: php, html, forms

I have seen many question are here, but I can not get the answer from that. so I have type the question again here. In a same page how can I get the `textarea` value.

My code is like this -

```
<?php
    $action = $_REQUEST['action'];
    $text =$_GET['text'];
    if(!$action){
        $device=file("abc.txt", FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES | FILE_SKIP_EMPTY_LINES);
        $lines =implode("\n",$device);
        echo "<form method='post' action='config.php'>";
        echo "<textarea name='text'  cols='40' rows='15'>$lines</textarea>";
        echo '<td> <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit"> </td></form>';
    }


    if($action == "submit" ){
    $ids = explode("\n", str_replace("\r", "", $input));
        echo $ids ;
    }
?>
```

Comment: Are you trying to get the value with `$_GET` when your form uses the post method?

Comment: ohhh....i have not marked yet

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You trying `$_GET` to get value of `textarea` but in `form` you are using `post` method.

Try

```
<?php
$action = $_POST['submit'];
$text = $_POST['text'];
if(!$action)
{
    $device=file("abc.txt", FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES | FILE_SKIP_EMPTY_LINES);
    $lines =implode("\n",$device);

    echo "<form method='post' action='config.php'>";
    echo "<textarea name='text'  cols='40' rows='15'>$lines</textarea>";
    echo '<td> <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit"> </td></form>';
}

if($action == "submit" )
{
    $ids = explode("\n", str_replace("\r", "", $text));
    echo $ids ; 
}
```

**FINAL UPDATE**

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{   
    $text = $_POST['text'];
    $ids = explode("\n", str_replace("\r", "", $text));
    echo $ids ; 
}
else
{
    $device = file("abc.txt", FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES | FILE_SKIP_EMPTY_LINES);
    $lines = implode("\n",$device);

    echo "<form method='post' action='config.php'>";
    echo "<textarea name='text' cols='40' rows='15'>$lines</textarea>";
    echo '<td><input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit"> </td></form>';
}
```

Comment: can you tell otherwise every thing is fine

Comment: @TOM why you are using `$action = $_REQUEST['action'];`?

Comment: for  ($action == "submit" ) but, it is not working

Comment: @TOM Because you haven't included an input with the name of `action` in your form.

Comment: can you show me which part i am  missing

Comment: @TOM I have updated my answer. Now it should work. Please see **UPDATE**

Comment: @TOM I have updated my answer again. Let me know if there is any issue,

Comment: you see your first answer .. i want when perform the submit action  , the value in the text area will show .

Comment: @TOM updated my answer again.

Answer (score 2):

If you send your form with the POST method - the value of "text" will be present in the `$_POST` array as `$_POST['text']`

If you send your form with method GET - it will be send over with the URL and can be fetched as `$_GET['text']`.